# R: How to filter a dataset on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset that consists of three variables: "customer_ID", "date", "Purchase_amount".

I need to apply a filter to the dataset that removes unique customer_ID's if they occur after a specified date.

I was thinking something like: `filter(df, !unique(customer_ID) & date>=2019-12-31)`
or maybe an `If()` function is better suited here.

**How should I go about this?**

----EDIT----

The context is that I'm trying to do a CLV analysis, which requires me to split the dataset into a estimation period and a holdout period. Every obsevation in the dataset mentioned above, represents a transaction a customer who makes at a given date for a given amount. The same customer can buy multiple times, which just results in the customer ID showing up mulitple times. In order to conduct the analysis, I need to remove all newly aquired customers from the holdout period, since I am only interested in the starting customer cohert, to see just how many of the customers from the estimation period, who decides to make another purchase in the holdout period.

To illustrate the problem, I have created some mock-up data:

```
ID=c(1,2,3,1,3,4)
date=c('2020-01-01','2020-01-05','2020-01-19','2020-02-03','2020-02-14','2020-02-21')
purchase_amount=c(24,20,19,30,22,24)
data.frame(ID,date,purchase_amount)
```

[image]

**I want to create a filter that removes every obsevation that contains an unique customer_ID that occurs after 2020-01-31.** In this example, that would mean that the customer with customer_ID 4 will be removed. Keep in mind that even though customer_ID 2 is unique, the transaction does not happen after the specified date, so it shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!all(date > as.Date('2020-01-31'))) %>%
  ungroup -> result

result

#     ID date       purchase_amount
#  <dbl> <date>               <dbl>
#1     1 2020-01-01              24
#2     2 2020-01-05              20
#3     3 2020-01-19              19
#4     1 2020-02-03              30
#5     3 2020-02-14              22
```

This will remove the `ID`'s where `all` the entries  are after `'2020-01-31'`.

Comment: This will do just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Ronaks solution, but with one more column:
Check with `case_when` for obsevation that contains an unique customer_ID that occurs after 2020-01-31, then
`filter`.

```
# your data
ID=c(1,2,3,1,3,4)
date=c('2020-01-01','2020-01-05','2020-01-19','2020-02-03','2020-02-14','2020-02-21')
purchase_amount=c(24,20,19,30,22,24)
df <- data.frame(ID,date,purchase_amount)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(logical = case_when(n() == 1 & date > as.Date('2020-01-31') ~ TRUE,
                              TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(logical == FALSE)

# Output:
     ID date       purchase_amount logical
  <dbl> <date>               <dbl> <lgl>  
1     1 2020-01-01              24 FALSE  
2     2 2020-01-05              20 FALSE  
3     3 2020-01-19              19 FALSE  
4     1 2020-02-03              30 FALSE  
5     3 2020-02-14              22 FALSE
```